# Python subprocess.run() cannot find R (Rscript) in Docker

Tags: python, r, docker, subprocess

I have a Python app which calls R as a subprocess that I am containerizing in Docker. Some Python snippets as follows:

```
import subprocess
check_ape = ['Rscript', './check_ape.R'] #called in the function 'R_cophen'
subprocess.run(check_ape)
```

I have tried adding `shell=TRUE` in subprocess.run() but this gives a different error and also then causes the app to fail on my laptop environment (otherwise it runs). It appears like it's failing to connect with R (PATH variable is set on my local system).

The error output is a standard Python error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "//main.py", line 355, in
>
> if **name** == '**main**': main()   File "//main.py", line 132, in main
> cophen, purge, pge_incr, z, _ = R_cophen('{}/{}'.format(dat_dir, tree), path2script) #get Dist Mat from phylogeny in R   File
> "//main.py", line 215, in R_cophen
> subprocess.run(check_ape) #....and install if not present   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in
> _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Rscript'

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.10
COPY . .
ADD main.py .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Not sure how relevant it is but the `COPY . .` instruction was added so the app can find files in the directory.

Comment: Is it `Rscript ./check_ape.R` successful to run in your built container?

Comment: Hi - no, that was my original script, seems like it doesn't matter. Thanks